# Why is `pw_gecos` named as such?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, passwd

In the passwd struct:

```
struct passwd {
    char   *pw_name;       /* username */
    char   *pw_passwd;     /* user password */
    uid_t   pw_uid;        /* user ID */
    gid_t   pw_gid;        /* group ID */
    char   *pw_gecos;      /* user information */
    char   *pw_dir;        /* home directory */
    char   *pw_shell;      /* shell program */
};
```

Referenced: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html

The `user information` (usually full name of the user) is found in an attribute `pw_gecos`. What does gecos mean, why is this named as such, and what is the history behind the name?

Comment: maybe [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) helps for this - seems to come from [General Comprehensive Operating System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Comprehensive_Operating_System).

Comment: @Petesh If you turn this into a fleshed out answer I would accept it, otherwise I will reference this and answer the question myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field):

> The gecos field, or GECOS field is an entry in the /etc/passwd file on
>   Unix, and similar operating systems.It is typically used to record
>   general information about the account or its user(s) such as their
>   real name and phone number.
>
> Some early Unix systems at Bell Labs used GECOS machines for print
>   spooling and various other services, so this field was added to carry
>   information on a user's GECOS identity.